# Добавление и сохранение имени пользователя в базе данных

Tags: python, база-данных

Есть код на Python для создания аккаунта, где нужно ввести имя. Как сделать так, чтобы в `db["user_names"]` автоматически добавлялось и сохранялось имя пользователя?

```py
from replit import db
db["user_names"]
db["balances"]
db["ban_accounts"]

print("Создание аккаунта!")
name = input("Введите ваш имя: ")
db["user_names"] = name
print("Ваш NickName: " + db["user_names"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from replit import db

db["user_names"] = db.get("user_names", []) # инициализация списка пользователей, если он еще не был создан
db["balances"] = db.get("balances", {}) # инициализация словаря балансов, если он еще не был создан
db["ban_accounts"] = db.get("ban_accounts", []) # инициализация списка заблокированных аккаунтов, если он еще не был создан

print("Создание аккаунта!")
name = input("Введите ваш имя: ")
db["user_names"] = db.get("user_names", []) + [name]
```

Comment: Последний `print` непонятен, он просто использует `name` из `input`, весь остальной код про `replit` никак не используется.